# The command WGET not working and sending an error

Tags: java, docker, jmeter, wget

I have created an image doing the following command :

```bash
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.2.1.tgz
```

So I commented this command, and directly went in my image to do the command. However, the wget fails, with the following message :

```
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.tgz
converted 'https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.tgz' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 'https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.tgz' (UTF-8)
--2020-04-22 12:24:57--  https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.tgz
Resolving archive.apache.org (archive.apache.org)... 138.201.131.134, 2a01:4f8:172:2ec5::2
Connecting to archive.apache.org (archive.apache.org)|138.201.131.134|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of 'archive.apache.org' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of 'archive.apache.org' hasn't got a known issuer.
```

Am I missing something basic with WGET?

Answer (score 1):

I changed my base image from `java:8` to `openjdk:8` and then `wget` command worked on it without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

First try to get proper certificate manager installed like below:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates //. command dependent on linux distro , please correct according to distro use
```

If you don't care about certificate , then you can pass following param with wget:

```
--no-check-certificate
```

like below:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.tgz
```

**Note:-** It's insecure option and can lead to Security Vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `--no-check-certificate` to the wget command could do the trick, but I don't recommend you to do it.

What base Docker image are you using? Maybe the `ca-certificates` package is not installed or is outdated.

Comment: it's hauptmedia/java:oracle-java8

Comment: You should think in moving from that image to the one that openjdk provides. That image uses the webupd8team repository which is no longer valid

Comment: Which one do you advise me to use??

Comment: take a look at https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk. Those are the official images from openjdk. You can also use the ones provided by Amazon at https://hub.docker.com/_/amazoncorretto